How to resolve differences between FFT frequency and real frequency after using scipy.fft.fft() in Python?
I am trying to perform a Fourier analysis on a randomly generated linear combination of sinusoids.  I am operating on a timescale from 0 min to 860 min (i.e. a total of 861 timepoints), and my function produces a sine wave at a default sampling rate of 1 sample/min (this is intended to replicate real timecourse data that I have gathered).  In order to avoid aliasing, I am interpolating my data 30X to a rate of 30 samples/min and running an FFT on the interpolated data.  I am then trying to pull the peak frequencies from that FFT analysis and compare them (visually) to the original known frequencies of the randomly generated sinusoid.
This is my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import detrend, find_peaks
from scipy.fft import fft, rfft, fftfreq, rfftfreq, fftshift


def make_sample_sin(time_length, max_freq = 15, sampling_rate = 1, num_waves = 3):
    """
    Generates randomized linear combinations of sine waves to use when testing Fourier analysis.

    Parameters
    ----------
    time_length : flt
        Total time (min)
    max_freq : flt, optional
        Maximum frequency to randomly sample.  The default is 15 cycles/min.
    sampling_rate : flt, optional
        Frequency of sample collection (samples/min).  The default is 1/min.
    num_waves : int, optional
        Number of sine waves to include in the linear combination.  The default is 3.

    Returns
    -------
    sin_dict : dict
        Dictionary of flattened 2D arrays of timecourse sinusoid data corresponding to each treatment
    freqs_dict : dict
        Dictionary of dicts containing the original frequencies of the component sine functions.
        Entries are of the form amp: freq.

    """
    sin_dict   = dict.fromkeys(["-PGN", "1X", "10X", "100X"])
    freqs_dict = dict.fromkeys(["-PGN", "1X", "10X", "100X"])
    
    times      = np.arange(time_length) / sampling_rate
    # print(times)
    
    for key in sin_dict:
        sin_array = np.zeros((0, time_length))
        freqs_all = []                                     # frequencies in cycles/min!!!
        
        for cell in range(10):
            signal      = np.zeros(time_length)
            freqs_cell  = {}
            
            for _ in range(num_waves):
                freq    = np.random.uniform(0.1, max_freq) # set random frequency
                amp     = np.random.uniform(0.5, 5)        # set random amplitude
                phase   = np.random.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)  # set random phase
                                
                # add random sine wave to signal
                signal += amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * times + phase)
                
                # add frequency to list
                freqs_cell[amp] = freq
            
            # reorder freqs_cell
            sorted_freqs_cell = {k: v for k, v in sorted(freqs_cell.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)}
            
            # update
            sin_array   = np.vstack((sin_array, signal))
            freqs_all.append(sorted_freqs_cell)
        
        sin_dict[key]   = sin_array
        freqs_dict[key] = freqs_all
    
    return sin_dict, freqs_dict, time_length, max_freq


def run_fft(subcluster_traces, test = False, interpolate = False, **kwargs):
    """
    Runs FFT on smoothed trace data.

    Parameters
    ----------
    subcluster_traces : dict
        Dictionary of ratio time trace values for cells in each subcluster within clusters for all treatments.
    test : bool, optional
        Whether or not the provided is test (e.g. random sinusoid) or experimental. The default is False.
    interpolate : bool, optional
        Whether or not to perform additional interpolation. The default is False.
    **sampling_rate : flt
        Frequency of sample collection (samples/min).  Must be provided.
    **max_freq : flt
        Maximum frequency of randomly sampled sines.  Must be provided if test is True.
    **interp_rate : int
        Degree of interpolation to perform.  Must be provided if interpolate is True.
    **time_length : int
        Total time (min).  Must be provided if test is True.
        

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        Occurs if sampling_rate is not provided.
        Occurs if interpolate is True and interp_rate is not provided.
        Occurs if test is True and max_freq or time_length are not provided.
        Occurs if sampling_rate < 2 * max_freq.
        Occurs if timesteps are not uniform.

    Returns
    -------
    data_dict : dict
        Dictionary of flattened 2D arrays of timecourse data contained in subcluster_traces corresponding to each treatment
    detrended_dict : dict
        Dictionary of flattened 2D arrays of smoothed, detrended data corresponding to each treatment
    y_dict : dict
        Dictionary of lists of cell names corresponding to each treatment
    fft_dict : dict
        Dictionary of complex ndarrays containing the 1D n-point DFT calculated using the FFT algorithm corresponding to each treatment
    fft_freq_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the DFT sample frequencies corresponding to each treatment
    fft_amp_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the amplitude of the complex points in fft_dict corresponding to each treatment
    fft_phase_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the phase angles of the complex points in fft_dict corresponding to each treatment
    fft_peak_dict : dict
        Dictionary of dfs containing the peak amplitude and the frequency at which it occurs for each cell in each treatment
    sampling_rate : flt
        Frequency of sample collection post-interpolation (if applicable) (1/min)
    """
    
    # check to make sure sampling_rate is provided
    if "sampling_rate" not in kwargs:
        raise ValueError("sampling_rate must be provided.")
    sampling_rate  = kwargs["sampling_rate"]                                    # sampling rate in samples/min
    
    # check to make sure interp_rate is provided if interpolate is True
    if interpolate:
        if "interp_rate" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("interp_rate must be provided when interpolation is True.")
        interp_rate    = kwargs["interp_rate"]
        sampling_rate *= interp_rate                                            # post-interpolation sampling rate in samples/min
    
    # check to make sure max_freq and time_length are provided if test is True
    if test:
        if "max_freq" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("max_freq must be provided when test is True.")
        max_freq       = kwargs["max_freq"]
        
        if "time_length" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("time_length must be provided when test is True.")
        time_length    = kwargs["time_length"]
        
        # check to make sure sampling rate is >= 2 * max_freq
        if sampling_rate < 2 * max_freq:
            raise ValueError("sampling_rate insufficienty high to prevent aliasing.  Additional interpolation required.")
    
    # flatten trace data (each row of data_dict is a cell and each column is a timepoint)
    # x_dict is times and y_dict is cells
    if test is False:
        x_dict, y_dict, data_dict = flatten_subcluster_traces(subcluster_traces)
    else:
        data_dict  = subcluster_traces
        
    treatments     = data_dict.keys()
    step_size      = 0
    
    detrended_dict = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    fft_dict       = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    fft_freq_dict  = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    fft_amp_dict   = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    fft_phase_dict = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    fft_peak_dict  = dict.fromkeys(treatments)
    
    for treatment, treatment_data in data_dict.items():
        print(f"Sampling rate (post-interpolation) ({treatment}): {sampling_rate}/min")
        
        # calculate number of samples (post-interpolation)
        # print(x_dict[treatment][-1])
        num_times  = sampling_rate * (x_dict[treatment][-1]) if test is False else sampling_rate * (time_length - 1)
        num_cells  = treatment_data.shape[0]
        print(f"# timepoints ({treatment}): {num_times}")
        print(f"# cells ({treatment}): {num_cells}")
        
        # calculate step size
        if test is False:
            step_sizes            = np.diff(x_dict[treatment])
            if np.all(step_sizes == step_sizes[0]):
                step_size         = step_sizes[0] / sampling_rate               # step size in minutes
            else:
                raise ValueError("Timesteps are not uniform.")
            # print(treatment, step_size)
        else:
            step_size             = 1 / sampling_rate                           # step size in minutes
        
        print(f"Step size (post-interpolation) ({treatment}): {step_size} min")
        
        if interpolate is True: # interpolate
            times                 = list(range(treatment_data.shape[1]))        # original times, in min
            times_int             = np.arange(times[0], times[-1], 1 / sampling_rate) # interpolated times, in sec
            # print(times_int)
            int_data              = np.array([np.interp(times_int, times, row) for row in treatment_data])
            # print(int_values.shape[1])
            
            # # plot random row to check interpolation (UNCOMMENT IF DESIRED)
            # rand_int = random.randint(0, len(treatment_data) - 1)
            # rand_data_org = treatment_data[rand_int]
            # rand_data_int = int_data[rand_int]
            # fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (16, 6), sharex = True, sharey = True)
            # axs[0].plot(times, rand_data_org, linewidth = 0.5, color = "blue")
            # axs[0].set_xlabel('Time')
            # axs[0].set_ylabel('Nuclear Relish fraction (fold change)')
            # axs[1].plot(times_int, rand_data_int, linewidth = 0.5, color = "red")
            # plt.suptitle(f'Comparing interpolated data ({treatment}, interp_rate = {interp_rate})')
            # plt.tight_layout()
        
        else:
            int_data              = treatment_data
        
        # print(f"Step size (post-interpolation ({treatment}): {step_size} sec\n")
        # print(f"Number of timepoints (post-interpolation ({treatment}): {num_times}")
        freq_bins                 = np.arange(0, num_times // 2) * (sampling_rate / num_times)
        freq_resolution           = sampling_rate / num_times
        print(f"Frequency bins ({treatment}): n = {len(freq_bins)} bins")
        print(f"Frequency resolution  ({treatment}): {freq_resolution} Hz/bin\n")
        
        # detrend data
        detrended_data            = detrend(int_data, axis = 1)
        detrended_dict[treatment] = detrended_data
        
        # run rfft
        fft_array                 = rfft(detrended_data)
        fft_dict[treatment]       = fft_array
        
        # # perform Hilbert transform
        # fft_array_shift           = fftshift(fft_array)
        # # print(detrended_data.shape[1]//2)
        # fft_array_shift[len(detrended_data) // 2 :] *= 2
        
        # get freqencies
        # window_length             = fft_array.shape[1]
        fft_freq_array            = rfftfreq(detrended_data.shape[1], d = step_size)
        fft_freq_dict[treatment]  = fft_freq_array
        
        # get amplitudes and scale to signal length
        fft_amp_array             = np.abs(fft_array) / num_times
        fft_amp_dict[treatment]   = fft_amp_array
        
        # get phase angles
        fft_phase_array           = np.angle(fft_array)
        fft_phase_dict[treatment] = fft_phase_array
        
        # make df of peak amplitudes and frequencies
        fft_peak_amp              = np.max(fft_amp_array, axis = 1)
        fft_peak_idx              = np.argmax(fft_amp_array, axis = 1)
        # print(f"Peak indices ({treatment}): ", len(fft_peak_idx))
        fft_peak_freq             = [fft_freq_array[idx] for idx in fft_peak_idx]
        # print(f"Peak amplitudes ({treatment}): ", len(fft_peak_amp))
        # print(f"Peak frequencies ({treatment}): ", len(fft_peak_freq))
        
        if test is False:
            amp_df                = pd.DataFrame(index = y_dict[treatment], columns = ["Peak amp.", "Peak freq."])
        else:
            amp_df                = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Peak amp.", "Peak freq."])
        amp_df["Peak amp."]       = fft_peak_amp
        amp_df["Peak freq."]      = fft_peak_freq
        fft_peak_dict[treatment]  = amp_df
    
    if test is False:
        return data_dict, detrended_dict, y_dict, fft_dict, fft_freq_dict, fft_amp_dict, fft_phase_dict, fft_peak_dict, sampling_rate
    else:
        return detrended_dict, fft_dict, fft_freq_dict, fft_amp_dict, fft_phase_dict, fft_peak_dict, sampling_rate



def plot_component_sinusoids(df_dict_smooth_org, detrended_dict, fft_dict, fft_freq_dict, fft_amp_dict, fft_phase_dict, sampling_rate, interp_rate = 1, test = False, **kwargs):
    """
    Plots component sinusoids corresponding to major peaks in Fourier spectrum.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_dict_smooth_org : dict
        Dictionary containing dataframes with smoothed ratio values for PGN, 1X, 10X, and 100X
    detrended_dict : dict
        Dictionary of flattened 2D arrays of smoothed, detrended data corresponding to each treatment
    fft_dict : dict
        Dictionary of complex ndarrays containing the 1D n-point DFT calculated using the FFT algorithm corresponding to each treatment
    fft_freq_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the DFT sample frequencies corresponding to each treatment
    fft_amp_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the amplitude of the complex points in fft_dict corresponding to each treatment
    fft_phase_dict : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the phase angles of the complex points in fft_dict corresponding to each treatment
    sampling_rate : flt
        Frequency of sample collection post-interpolation (if applicable) (1/min)
    test : bool, optional
        Whether or not the provided is test (e.g. random sinusoid) or experimental. The default is False.
    **interp_rate : int
        Degree of interpolation to perform.  The default is 1.
    **cells_dict : dict
        Dictionary of lists of cell names corresponding to each treatment.  Must be provided if test is False.
    **sin_freqs : dict
        Dictionary of arrays containing the original frequencies of component sine functions.  Must be provided if test is True.
        Entries are of the form amp: freq.
    
    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        Occurs if test is False and cells_dict is not provided.
        Occurs if test is True and sin_freqs is not provided.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    print(f"Post-interpolation sampling rate: {sampling_rate:.1f}/min")
    
    # check to make sure cells_dict is provided if test is False
    if test is False:
        if "cells_dict" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("cells_dict must be provided when test is False.")
        cells_dict = kwargs["cells_dict"]
    
    # check to make sure sin_freqs is provided if test is True
    else:
        if "sin_freqs" not in kwargs:
            raise ValueError("sin_freqs must be provided when test is True.")
        sin_freqs = kwargs["sin_freqs"]
        
    for i, (treatment, fft_array) in enumerate(fft_dict.items()): # iterate over treatments
        # retrieve frequencies and cell names
        cells      = cells_dict[treatment] if test is False else None
        freqs      = fft_freq_dict[treatment]
        
        # retrieve original frequencies if running test
        sin_treat  = sin_freqs[treatment] if test is True else None
        
        # randomly select cell to plot
        cell_idx   = np.random.randint(0, fft_array.shape[0])
        # print(treatment, cell_idx)
        cell_name  = cells[cell_idx] if test is False else f"Test curve {i + 1}-{cell_idx}"
        # print(treatment, cell_name)
        cell_data  = fft_array[cell_idx]
        cell_amps  = fft_amp_dict[treatment][cell_idx]
        cell_angs  = fft_phase_dict[treatment][cell_idx]
        
        # retrieve peak amplitudes and frequencies
        # # limit to positive frequencies (wholly real signals) - NOT NECESSARY WHEN rfft() IS USED IN run_fft()
        # pos_idxs   = np.where(freqs >= 0)[0]
        # # print(pos_idxs)
        # pos_freqs  = freqs[pos_idxs]
        # # print("Initial: ", type(pos_freqs))
        # pos_freqs  = np.array([freq / (60 * sampling_rate) for freq in pos_freqs])     # transform FFT frequencies to real frequencies (in Hz)
        # # print("Final: ", type(pos_freqs))
        # pos_data   = cell_data[pos_idxs]
        # pos_amps   = cell_amps[pos_idxs]
        # pos_angs   = cell_angs[pos_idxs]
        
        # # check to make sure the correct number of data points have been extracted
        # if len(set([len(pos_freqs), len(pos_data), len(pos_amps), len(pos_angs)])) != 1:
        #     raise ValueError("Positive frequency indexing incorrect.")
        
        # find peaks among positive frequencies
        max_amp    = cell_amps.max()
        # nyquist    = sampling_rate / 2
        # threshold  = max_amp / 20
        # height     = max_amp / 20
        prom       = max_amp / 10
        # print(f"Threshold ({treatment}): ", threshold)
        peak_idxs  = find_peaks(cell_amps, prominence = prom, distance = 5)[0]
        # peak_idxs  = findpeaks(pos_data, method = "peakdetect")
        peak_freqs = freqs[peak_idxs]
        peak_amps  = cell_amps[peak_idxs]
        peak_angs  = cell_angs[peak_idxs]
        # print(f"Peak amplitudes ({treatment}): ", peak_amps)
        # print(f"Peak frequencies ({treatment}): ", peak_freqs)
        
        # sort peaks in descending order of amplitude
        num_peaks  = len(peak_idxs)
        # print(f"Number of peaks ({treatment}): ", num_peaks)
        # sort_idxs  = np.argsort(peak_amps)[::-1]
        # print(sort_idxs)
        peak_tuples = zip(peak_freqs, peak_amps, peak_angs)
        peak_dict = {idx: [freq, amp, ang] for idx, (freq, amp, ang) in enumerate(peak_tuples)}
        # print(peak_dict)
        sorted_dict = sorted(peak_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
        # print(sorted_dict)
        peak_freqs  = [item[1][0] for item in sorted_dict]
        peak_amps   = [item[1][1] for item in sorted_dict]
        peak_angs   = [item[1][2] for item in sorted_dict]
        # print(f"Peak amplitudes ({treatment}): ", peak_amps)
        # print(f"Peak frequencies ({treatment}): ", peak_freqs)
        # print(f"Peak phase angles ({treatment}): ", peak_angs)
        
        # plot original trace on first plot
        if test is False:
            # initialize figure
            fig, axs   = plt.subplots(2, max(3, num_peaks), figsize=(8 * (1 + min(num_peaks, len(fft_array))), 16))
            
            # print(treatment, cell_name)
            trace  = df_dict_smooth_org[treatment][cell_name]
        else:
            # initialize figure
            fig, axs   = plt.subplots(3, max(3, num_peaks), figsize=(8 * (1 + min(num_peaks, len(fft_array))), 24))
            
            trace  = df_dict_smooth_org[treatment][cell_idx, :]
            sines  = sin_treat[cell_idx]
        
        times      = np.linspace(0, len(trace) - 1, len(trace))
            
        # print(cell_name, f" ({treatment}): ", trace)
        axs[0, 0].plot(times, trace)
        axs[0, 0].set_title("Original trace", fontsize = 20)
        axs[0, 0].set_xlabel("Time (min)", fontsize = 15)
        axs[0, 0].set_ylabel("Nuclear Relish fraction (fold change)", fontsize = 15)
        
        # plot detrended and interpolated trace on second plot
        times_detrended = np.arange(0, (detrended_dict[treatment].shape[1]) / sampling_rate, 1 / sampling_rate)
        # print(f"Original times (len = {len(times)}): {times}")
        # print(f"Detrended/interpolated times (len = {len(times_detrended)}): {times_detrended}")
        detrended_trace = detrended_dict[treatment][cell_idx]
        axs[0, 1].plot(times_detrended, detrended_trace)
        axs[0, 1].axhline(y = 0, color = "grey", linestyle = "--", linewidth = 0.5)
        axs[0, 1].set_title(f"Detrended and interpolated trace (interp = {interp_rate}X)", fontsize = 20)
        axs[0, 1].set_xlabel("Time (min)", fontsize = 15)
        axs[0, 1].set_ylabel ("Detrended nuclear Relish fraction (fold change)", fontsize = 15)
        
        # plot original FFT amplitude on third plot
        axs[0, 2].plot(freqs, cell_amps)
        axs[0, 2].set_title("Fast Fourier Transform", fontsize = 20)
        axs[0, 2].set_xlabel("Frequency (cycles/min)", fontsize = 15)
        axs[0, 2].set_ylabel("Amplitude", fontsize = 15)
        
        for i, peak_freq in enumerate(peak_freqs): # plot sinusoid corresponding to each of the peak frequencies
            # retrieve sine curve
            print(f"{treatment} ({cell_name}): Peak frequency ({i + 1}) = {peak_freq:.3e} Hz")
            amp    = peak_amps[i]
            phase  = peak_angs[i]
            sine   = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * peak_freq * times + phase)
            
            # plot
            axs[1, i].plot(times, sine)
            if peak_freq < 0.01:
                axs[1, i].set_title(f"{peak_freq:.3e} Hz (Amplitude = {amp:.3f})", fontsize = 20)
            else:
                axs[1, i].set_title(f"{peak_freq:.3f} Hz (Amplitude = {amp:.3f})", fontsize = 20)
            axs[1, i].set_xlabel("Time (min)", fontsize = 15)
            axs[1, i].set_ylabel("Amplitude", fontsize = 15)
       
        sines_round = {round(amp, 3): round(freq, 3) for amp, freq in sines.items()}
        freqs_round = ', '.join(map(str, sines_round.values()))
        print(f"{treatment} ({cell_name}): {{original_amp: original_freq}} = {sines_round}")
        print("\n")
        
        for i, (org_amp, org_freq) in enumerate(sines.items()): # plot sinusoid corresponding to each of the original frequencis
            sine   = org_amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * org_freq * times)
            
            # plot
            axs[2, i].plot(times, sine)
            axs[2, i].set_title(f"Original frequency: {org_freq:.3f} 1/min", fontsize = 20)
            axs[2, i].set_xlabel("Time (min)", fontsize = 15)
            axs[2, i].set_ylabel("Amplitude", fontsize = 15)
        
        if test is False:
            plt.suptitle(f"{cell_name} ({treatment}): Sampling rate = {sampling_rate:.1f}/min", fontsize = 25)
        else:
            plt.suptitle(f"{cell_name}: Frequencies = {freqs_round} 1/min\nSampling rate = {sampling_rate:.1f}/min", fontsize = 25)
        
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.92)
        plt.show()
    

# test calls
test_sin_dict, test_sin_freqs, test_sin_time_length, test_sin_max_freq = make_sample_sin(861, max_freq = 15)
test_sin_detrended_dict, test_sin_fft_dict, test_sin_fft_freq_dict, test_sin_fft_amp_dict, test_sin_fft_phase_dict, test_sin_fft_peak_dict, test_sampling_rate = run_fft(test_sin_dict, test = True, interpolate = True, sampling_rate = 1, interp_rate = 30, time_length = test_sin_time_length, max_freq = test_sin_max_freq)
plot_component_sinusoids(test_sin_dict, test_sin_detrended_dict, test_sin_fft_dict, test_sin_fft_freq_dict, test_sin_fft_amp_dict, test_sin_fft_phase_dict, test_sampling_rate, interp_rate = 30, test = True, sin_freqs = test_sin_freqs)

Please make sure test = True for all calls to functions.  (There are test calls at the bottom of the code snippet which should allow you to run the functions as intended.)  Certain artifacts (e.g. the case when test = False and the use of scipy.signal.detrend are there for the purposes of processing the real timecourse data).
This is an example of one of the plots produced by my function:
FFT analysis of randomly generated linear combination of sinusoids
Note that the order of the subplots is as follows:

Row 1: Original trace; interpolated trace; FFT frequency/amplitude graph
Row 2: Component sinusoids corresponding to the peak frequencies isolated by the FFT
Row 3: Component sinusoids corresponding to the original frequencies generated by make_sample_sin

Since I am producing sine waves without noise, I am expecting these values to be the same; however, the calculated FFT frequencies (denoted by peak_freq in the plot_component_sinusoids function) are observably not the same as the original frequencies (denoted by org_freq in the plot_component_sinusoids function).  How can I resolve this discrepancy?  Or have I just failed to correctly extract the desired frequency values/made some other silly mistake?
I am relatively new to using the FFT for computational analysis, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Hey and welcome! nice question, I recommend you make it much simpler, post relevant parts and some data so others can reproduce your problem. Currently the code snippet contains a lot of bells and whistles...

The code is taken from the test case of a data analysis pipeline---I didn't want to remove too much processing in the event that I accidentally deleted the relevant section.  The snippet includes test calls so that you should be able to reproduce the problem if you just copy the code in its entirety and run it unaltered.

Please read [mre]. The request above is not about posting only a portion of your code, but about creating an example script that replicates the problem, and doesn’t do all the irrelevant stuff. You have way too much code right now for someone to want to look trough it and understand what you’re doing.

"In order to avoid aliasing, I am interpolating my data 30X to a rate of 30 samples/min and running an FFT on the interpolated data." You should be aware that linear interpolating a signal will change what frequencies are present in the signal. See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/23527/4114

Also, please qualify the differences you see. I think the frequencies you extracted match quite well. What are you worried about? Is it not precise enough? Is the phase wrong?
